# ReactJS disabling form if checkbox is checked

Tags: reactjs, forms, checkbox

I have a checkbox. If the checkbox is checked, the form should close. But it doesn't work for me. I have the following code:

```
const [IsChacked, setIsChacked] = useState(false);

const onChangeParams = (name, setChackedValue, defaultChecked) => {
    if (name === "foreign_citizen") {
        let value = defaultChecked.target.value;           
        setChackedValue(name, value)
        if (parseInt(value) === 1) {
            setIsChacked(true);
        }
    }
};
```

And my form like this:

```
<Form.Check
  onChange={(e => onChangeParams("foreign_citizen", e, setChackedValue))}
  name="foreign_citizen"
  defaultChecked={values.foreign_citizen}
  isInvalid={touched.foreign_citizen && !!errors.foreign_citizen}
  type="checkbox"
  label="Наличие паспорта в деле"   />



{IsChacked ? (< > Dos something here</>) : ( <></>)}
```

If i checked on checkbox it gives like error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined

So where i have wrong? I don't undersanding...

Comment: e.target.checked instead of e.target.value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onChange={(e => onChangeParams("foreign_citizen", e, setChackedValue))}` here event object is second param

```
const onChangeParams = (name, setChackedValue, defaultChecked) => {
    if (name === "foreign_citizen") {
        let value = defaultChecked.target.value;
```

but above event object is 3rd param

try changing 
`onChange={(e => onChangeParams("foreign_citizen", setChackedValue, e,))}`

Also you have to enclose the Form in a Fragemnt

```
 return (
    <>
      <Form.Check
        onChange={(e => onChangeParams("foreign_citizen", setChackedValue, e,))}
        name="foreign_citizen"
        defaultChecked={values.foreign_citizen}
        isInvalid={touched.foreign_citizen && !!errors.foreign_citizen}
        type="checkbox"
        label="Наличие паспорта в деле"
      />
      {IsChacked ? <> Dos something here</> : <></>}
    </>
  );
```

A similar codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-blackwell-e7uhy

Comment: no solution, it returned TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined

Comment: e.target.checked instead of e.target.value

Comment: Yeah, i did like that, But there doesn't resolve. if i check it returned targer undefined error still.

Comment: Check this - https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-blackwell-e7uhy